# I am unable to share files in local network

Tags: wireless

how can i share my files using 'Local Network Share"?
i am unable to install sharing service.
following error occured.
[image]
 i use     `apt-get install -f`
   it gives flowing output

```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 310 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T and run the command `sudo apt-get install -f`  Take the output, no screenshot, and add the output to your question. Don't use the comments for that, use the [Edit] link.

Comment: i solve ths problem simpley  by updating software and retry the above process